# How to dismiss Facebook video fullscreen right-click menu?

Tags: google-chrome, video, facebook

When watching a Facebook video in Full Screen mode (in Chrome), I sometimes right-click as a misclick. This bring up a menu with options to {`Pause`,`Mute`,`Show Video URL`} , like this :

[image]

I want to dismiss the menu without interrupting the video playback. How can I do this?

**I have tried, with results:**

- `Right-click` on menu, does nothing
- `Right-click` outside menu, opens menu in another location
- `Left-click` on menu, performed selected action
- `Left-click` outside menu, dismisses menu but pauses video - `Left-click` again to play
- `Esc`, exits full-screen

**ADDENDA:**
Whilst posting this question I answered it for myself, although only by selecting a non-intuitive option. I leave this question in case it either helps someone else or there is a more intuitive solution I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the option `Show Video URL` has the effect of cancelling the menu pop-up and performs a benign action with no persistent display artifact.

Answer (score 0):

just click the right or left arrow on the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Middle-clicking (clicking the scroll wheel) on any of the actions closes the menu without performing the clicked action.